# How to get first P2P price from Binance to google sheets

Tags: html, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, binance

I'm trying to get first price from https://p2p.binance.com/ru/trade/all-payments/USDT?fiat=UZS
to Google Sheets.

I tried to use

```
=IMPORTXML("https://p2p.binance.com/ru/trade/all-payments/USDT?fiat=UZS";"//div[@class='css-1ee59nr']")
```

and

```
=IMPORTXML("https://p2p.binance.com/ru/trade/all-payments/USDT?fiat=UZS";"/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/main/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]")
```

Answer (score -1):

IMOPORTXML formula (or any other IMPORT formula) does not support the scrapping of JavaScript elements. you can always test this by disabling JS for a given site and usually only what is left can be imported. in your case:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! MB you know how to solve my case in a different way?

Comment: @РобертГумеров in most cases, the same stuff can be found on different websites, and if you are lucky it will be JS clean